# Why do some header files require libraries to be linked, in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

I'm building a socket program in Visual Studio 2003 .NET

I `#include <winsock2.h>` header file but also noticed that I had to link in the `WS2_32.lib` to fix the unresolved winsock function errors.

In other homework projects, I just added a header file and used it's functions - without adding the corresponding library.

How is this so?

Are some standard header file libraries already pre-linked in Visual Studio or something else?

Thank You!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The socket functions are actually implemented in `ws2_32.dll`. In order for the linker to be able to find them, you need to add the `ws2_32.lib` *import library* to your project. Note that the import library does not contain the actual code for the functions, but only information about where to find the actual functions (in `ws2_32.dll`).

You don't mention which other header files you're referring to, but if it's something like `<string.h>` then that is already in the MSVC runtime library; if it's something like `<windows.h>` then those functions are provided by import libraries such as `kernel32.lib`, `user32.lib`, and `gdi32.lib`. Those libraries are probably already included in your linker settings.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that the import library does not contain the actual code but only information about where to find the actual functions. yes, the other common header examples are ones you listed.

Comment: On that note, keep in mind that there are two kinds of libraries with the `.lib` extension - import libraries and static libraries. Static libraries *do* contain the actual code for the functions and don't have an associated `.dll`.

Comment: can the same .lib be linked in either way or does it usually come in one or the other?

Comment: @Tommy A .lib file is either an import lib or a static lib. Some libraries ship multiple .lib files, an import lib and a static lib.

Comment: A .lib usually comes in "one or the other" way. But there are also libraries that come as static lib and as .DLL with import lib.

Comment: @David: I meant that some come in both ways, although they may have slightly different names, as I explain in the rest of the comment.

Answer (score 6):

By default, Visual Studio includes the most commonly used Win32 .lib files, e.g. kernel32.lib, user32.lib, advapi32.lib etc. For more esoteric libraries, you need to add the .lib files yourself.

Answer (score 2):

By default Visual Studio will link against the standard library, so if you are including a header that is part of that then you don't need to explicitly add the library.  This is true for things like `stdio.h`, `iostream` and `stdlib.h`.

There are also some header files such as those used by the Standard Template Library (someone will be along in a minute to say that it's actually just called the 'Standard Library', but most books I've ever read, and Microsoft's docs too refer to the STL) such as `<vector>` and `<list>` which define all their code as templates that get expanded into the full functions by the compiler so that they don't need to link in a library.

A slight aside: there's also a mechanism for automatically linking against a library.  Just add:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
```

somewhere in your code.  Boost uses this technique so that it links against the correct build of the library depending on your compiler settinsg.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with Visual Studio; this is how compilation of C/C++ works.

All a header does is declare or define symbols. Functions, variables, typedefs, classes, etc.

A header can say:

```
int SomeFunction();
```

This is a function declaration. In order for you to compile code that uses `SomeFunction`, you must declare that `SomeFunction` exists. And this declaration must be made *before* your code that uses it.

These declarations are typically in header files.

However, a declaration is also a promise. A function *definition* is the actual C/C++ source code that makes the function work. A declaration says, "at some later point, you will be able to find the definition of this." This is a promise you are making to the compiler and linker.

You cannot successfully link C/C++ code unless all declarations in use have a *definition*. Some of these definitions come from your own compiled code, but some of them come from external libraries. External libraries have header files that provide the *declaration* of C/C++ functions, types, etc. But they also have library files (in VC++, these use the .lib extension) that provide the *definition* of those functions.

If you use declarations from a header, without linking to the library files that provide the *definition* of those symbols, you get a linker error.

Note that header files can contain definitions as well; much of the C++ standard library, and must of Boost is defined solely by header files. So there are no libraries to include. The library's documentation should tell you whether there is a .lib to link against or not.